# JDK java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet.equals(Object o) implementation efficiency

Tags: performance, collections, iterator, java

The `equals`implementatin of `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet` in JDK is as following

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // Override AbstractSet version to avoid calling size()
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Set))
        return false;
    Collection<?> c = (Collection<?>) o;
    try {
        return containsAll(c) && c.containsAll(this);
    } catch (ClassCastException unused) {
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I think the code below seems to be more efficient

```
public boolean myEquals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Set))
        return false;
    Collection<?> c = (Collection<?>) o;
    if (c.size() != this.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    Iterator ic = c.iterator();
    Iterator id = iterator();

    while (ic.hasNext() && id.hasNext()) {
        if (!ic.next().equals(id.next())) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And a simple test is also likely supporting the second `equals`

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer> set1 = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer>();
        ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer> set2 = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            set1.add(i);
            set2.add(i);
        }

        long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(set1.equals(set2));
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - ts);

        ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(myset1.myEquals(myset2));
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - ts);
    }
}
```

Output result

```
true
2713
true
589
```

In the JDK comment it says, `This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface.` Could anyone kindly explain this?

Comment: Your code assumes both collections are ordered. Theirs doesn't.

Comment: @EJP Actually `ConcurrentSkipListSet` extends `NavigableSet` which extends `SortedSet`

Comment: Please discuss your issue in core-libs-dev@openjdk.java.net mailing list.

Comment: Thanks @Fairoz, I'll post it later.

Comment: Sorry @EJP, I misunderstood, `this` is ordered, but the parameter of `equals()` i.e., `Object o` may be not ordered. thanks

Comment: Just a note, place use JMH to write/test microbenchmarks. There's too many mistakes you can make and too many other factors that may impact performance. http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, the [OpenJDK thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2017-May/047907.html) resulted in creating [JDK-8181146 ConcurrentSkipListSet.equals efficiency](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8181146).

> In the JDK comment it says, `This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface.` Could anyone kindly explain this?

It comes from [Set.equals(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). Per the documentation:

> Returns true if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set). This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface.

It is implying that `Set.equals` implementations should be defined by the behavior of [Set.contains(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-).  Which then leads you to this verbiage from the [java.util.SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if the sorted set is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See the Comparable interface or Comparator interface for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted set performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted set, equal. The behavior of a sorted set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.

So why the 'this contains that and that contains this' in the `ConcurrentSkipListSet`?  First off you want to avoid the call to [ConcurrentSkipListSet.size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html#size--) because:

> Beware that, unlike in most collections, this method is NOT a constant-time operation. Because of the asynchronous nature of these sets, determining the current number of elements requires traversing them all to count them. Additionally, it is possible for the size to change during execution of this method, in which case the returned result will be inaccurate. Thus, this method is typically not very useful in concurrent applications.

The second reason is that you want to be 'consistent with equals'.

Let's make a cruel example based off your code:

```
private static boolean myEquals(Set o1, Set o2) {
    if (o1.size() == 1 && o2.size() == 1) {
        Iterator ic = o2.iterator();
        Iterator id = o1.iterator();

        while (ic.hasNext() && id.hasNext()) {
            if (!ic.next().equals(id.next())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return o1.equals(o2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(skiplist(new BigDecimal("1.0")), tree(new BigDecimal("1.00")));
    print(skiplist(new BigDecimal("1.0")), hash(new BigDecimal("1.00")));
    print(skiplist(new BigDecimal("1.0")), identity(new BigDecimal("1.00")));
    print(skiplist(BigDecimal.ONE), identity(new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ONE, 0)));
}

private static Collection<BigDecimal> e() {
    return Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal("1.0"));
}

private static <E> Set<E> hash(E... e) {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(e));
}

private static <E> Set<E> skiplist(E... e) {
    return new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(Arrays.asList(e));
}

private static <E> Set<E> tree(E... e) {
    return new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(e));
}

private static <E> Set<E> identity(E... e) {
    Set<E> s = Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<E, Boolean>());
    Collections.addAll(s, e);
    return s;
}

private static void print(Set o1, Set o2) {
    System.out.println(o1.getClass().getName()
            + "==" + o2.getClass().getName() + ": "
            + o1.equals(o2) + ": " + myEquals(o1, o2));
    System.out.println(o2.getClass().getName()
            + "==" + o1.getClass().getName() + ": " + o2.equals(o1)
            + ": " + myEquals(o2, o1));
}
```

Which outputs:

```
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet==java.util.TreeSet: true: false
java.util.TreeSet==java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet: true: false
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet==java.util.HashSet: false: false
java.util.HashSet==java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet: false: false
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet==java.util.Collections$SetFromMap: false: false
java.util.Collections$SetFromMap==java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet: false: false
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet==java.util.Collections$SetFromMap: false: true
java.util.Collections$SetFromMap==java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet: false: true
```

That output shows that the new implementation would not be [consistent with equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.

Now we could fix this by replacing the element check with 
`((Comparable) e1).compareTo((Comparable) e2) != 0` or `Comparator.compare(e1, e2) != 0` and add checks to try to determine that the two sets use the same ordering but keep in mind that collections can be wrapped and there is nothing stopping a caller from [hiding the fact that a set is backed by sorted set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-).  Now you are back to the 'this contains that and that contains this' implementation of equals which can deal with collection wrappers.

Another nice property of the 'this contains that and that contains this' implementation is that the equals implementation is not creating an iterator object for the given collection which in the worst case could have an implementation like `Arrays.asList(s.toArray()).iterator()` under the hood.

Without relaxing spec, relaxing the existing behavior, or adding a collection method that returns a [`BiPredicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) to capture the 'equivalence relationship' for a collection, I think it will be hard to add an optimization like this to the JDK.